# TypeScript | How to return another class from Promise.then()

Tags: node.js, typescript, asynchronous, promise

I have a class in TypeScript, which extends Promise (MyClass extends Promise) my intention is that when calling then() a new instance of MyClass is returned.

```
class MyClass<I extends Arcaela.Object[] = []> extends Promise<I> {

private MyClass = MyClass;

constructor(executor: I | Promise<I> | (()=>I | Promise<I>)){
    super((done, failure)=>{
        try {
            if(typeof executor==='function')
                done( executor() );
            else if(executor instanceof Promise)
                executor.then( done ).catch( failure );
            else done( executor );
        } catch(err){ failure( err ); }
    });
}


then(filled: (value?: I)=> I | Promise<I>, outfilled?: ()=> any) : MyClass<I> {
    return super.then(current=>{
        delete current.status;
        return current;
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to make it clearer? It looks like you're writing a Singleton, but really not sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: e_i_pi answer good... i fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an object to return a string value, use the [magic __toString method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring)

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->var;
}
```